# number of partial orders modulo a fixed number

Tags: co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory

Let p(n) be the number of partial orders on the set {1,...,n}.  From the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, we find that the known values of p(n) are 
{1,1,3,19,219,4231,130023,6129859,431723379,44511042511,6611065248783,1396281677105899,414864951055853499,171850728381587059351,98484324257128207032183,77567171020440688353049939,83480529785490157813844256579,122152541250295322862941281269151,241939392597201176602897820148085023}.

We see that the units digits of these numbers appear to cycle with a period of length four: 1, 3, 9, 9.

Experiments with other moduli indicate that given a prime modulus m, the sequence cycles with a period of length m-1.  If the modulus m is a prime power, then the period appears to be of length phi(m), where phi is Euler's phi-function.  For any modulus m, the period appears to be of length the least common multiple (LCM) of the constituent period lengths.  For example, if m=12, the period appears to be of length LCM(phi(4),phi(3))=LCM(2,2)=2.

I don't know how to prove this conjecture and I don't see any reference to it.  If proved, perhaps this result together with an asymptotic estimate for p(n) could be used to find higher values of p(n).

Comment: The link to the OEIS sequence A001035:
http://oeis.org/A001035

Comment: This is a really nifty conjecture. My gut is skeptical that the period will always work out to exactly $p-1$, but even the claim that a period exists is cool. The only way I can think of approaching it is to show (for fixed $p$) that almost all posets have an automorphism of order $p$, so they don't contribute to the count mod $p$, and proving some sort of recursion for posets without such an automorphism. Good luck!

Comment: Following David's idea, could you carry this out just for p=2?

Comment: I'm less skeptical, due to the related result here http://www.springerlink.com/content/r876140434386j86/. I haven't looked at the paper beyond the first page but it may help

Comment: Just realized I asked for slightly the wrong thing above. For a poset P, let a(P) be the order of the automorphism group of P. Then your quantity is the sum over all isomorphism classes of order n poset of n!/a(P). So the only terms that contribute to the sum are those where a(P) is divisible by as many powers of p as n! is. So we need large automorphism groups, not small ones... (continued)

Comment: Since Aut(P) is a subgroup of S_n, another way to state this is that we only care about the cases where Aut(P) and S_n have the same p-sylow. In other words, we want to look at posets which are preserved by Sylow_p(S_n). Since Sylow_p(S_n) is pretty easy to describe explicitly, this might be a good starting point. 

Comment: Ah, if I'd gone over to page 2 in the above Borevich reference, I'd have seen that your conjecture is Theorem 1. He doesn't give a detailed proof (or even a reference - apparently 'it is recounted in another place' !) but does give some hints.

Comment: Re David Speyer's "So the only terms that contribute to the sum are those where a(P) is divisible by as many powers of p as n! is": it seems that there are only a bounded number of posets P where this is true: one orbit of Aut(P) has to have (n - (n mod p)) elements, so the number of these highly symmetric posets is the same as the number of posets on 1+(n mod p) elements in which one of the elements (the one corresponding to the big orbit) is distinguished from the others.

Comment: @David Eppstein: Not quite. I get that the posets whose automorphism group contains a $p$-sylow are obtained as follows: Let $n$ in base $p$ be $\sum a_i p^i$. Build a poset $S$ on $\sum a_i$ elements. Then take $a_1$ elements of $S$ and replace them with $p$ indistinguishable elements, take $a_2$ elements and replace them with $p^2$ indistinguishable elements and so forth. So the largest orbit is $p^{\lfloor \log_p n \rfloor}$.

Comment: I feel like it should be easy to finish the proof from this description, but I'm missing some of the details. Feel free to write it up if you get it.

Comment: Just to add: Borevich eventually wrote up a proof of your conjecture here http://www.springerlink.com/content/g654831527p1561v/

Comment: I might humbly point out that Borevich leaves aside prime powers as *too unwieldy* and that my proof is shorter. We don't need the Sylow subgroups of the full automorphism group. Just some appropriate group acting on the orders. In this case a cyclic one.

Comment: A beautiful proof, Aaron!  ---Martin

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For q prime, enlarge  $\{ 1,\cdots,m \}$ to a set of size $n=m+(q-1)$ by replacing $m$ by $q$ clones $m_1 , m_2 , \cdots , m_q$ and consider the $q$-cycle $\sigma=(m_1\ m_2\ \cdots \ m_q)$. It acts on the set of partial orders of the $n$-set and each of its orbits has size 1 or size q. Each orbit of size 1 arises from a unique partial order of the $m$-set by having all $p$ clones behave identically to the original. This proves that $p(m+(q-1)) \equiv p(m) \mod q $  I think I see how to generalize to $q^k$ but I'll have to think about it. The same idea should apply to a wider variety of structures, but which ones?

**later** The argument seems as if it should work for bipartite graphs on n labelled vertices and also connected bipartite graphs *except for powers of 2* The data at OEIS supports this as far as it goes, ignoring the numbers for less than 3 vertices. 
http://www.oeis.org/A047864  http://www.oeis.org/A001832

It also works for appropriate restricted classes such as series parallel networks with n labelled vertices and parallel edges allowed. http://www.oeis.org/A053554

Here is my argument for why $p(n+\phi(q^2)) \equiv p(n) \mod q^2$. I think it generalizes to $q^k$: Further enlarge the $n$ set above to one of size $m+q^2-1=n+\phi(q^2)=N$ by replacing each clone $m_i$ by $q$ clones $m_{i1}, m_{i2}, \cdots ,m_{iq}$ and consider the $q^2$ cycle $$\tau=(m_{11}m_{21}\cdots m_{q1}m_{12}m_{22}\cdots m_{q,q})$$ It acts on partial orders of the $N$-set and the action has orbits of size 1, $q$ and $q^2$. The orbits of size less than $q^2$ are in bijective correspondence with the orbits of the same size for the action of $\sigma$ on partial orders of the $n$-set.